# Como detectar o mouse wheel?

Tags: c#

Preciso detectar se o usuário está rolando o scroll do mouse para baixo.

Tentei com o `GetKeyState`, mas parece que não tem como passar como parâmetro a rolagem do scroll do mouse.

Encontrei também [isso](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms646254(v=vs.85).aspx), mas não consegui entender como se usa no C#.

Código:

```
if (/* Aqui eu devo checar se o usuário está rolando o scroll */)
{
    Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
    s.Start();
    while (s.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300))
    {
        //Irrelevante
    }
    s.Stop();
}
```

Achei também [isso](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousewheeleventargs.delta.aspx), mas não faço nem ideia de como usar em uma aplicação console.

Comment: qual o proposito ? windows forms ?

Comment: Aplicação console.

Comment: Não sei se tem esta funcionalidade para console.

Comment: veja se ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302891/get-wheel-delta-wparam-macro-in-c-sharp

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Eu tinha chegado nessa pergunta já antes de fazer a minha própria. Eu não entendi nada do que se passa lá kkk

Comment: Se falar qual o propósito que você precisa, talvez fique mais fácil ajudar

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Ué, preciso detectar se o usuario está rolando o scroll para baixo para executar um código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe algumas maneiras.

1. Chame  [ReadConsoleInput](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/ReadConsoleInput.html)  você receberá um `MOUSE_WHEELED` se o whell do mouse for rodado.
2. Crie um programa Windows.Form sem o ambiente windows.form assim você terá as propriedades do mouse em um ambiente console! [Essa seria a minha escolha]

---

ex de windows.Form sem o formulário, apenas o console.

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new WindowlessApplicationContext());

    }
}


internal class WindowlessApplicationContext : ApplicationContext
{
    public WindowlessApplicationContext()
    {
        try
        {
            //Your code

        }
        // you mayy add catch here
        finally
        {
            //Close process
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Mais informações:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856386/capturing-mouse-wheel-events-in-console-application

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/ReadConsoleInput.html

Comment: O problema de fazer com o forms, é que eu estou injetando o código em outro processo, nisso eu acho que não funcionaria nem com um overlay. Poderia me dar um exemplo da primeira maneira?

Comment: bom..ainda acho que o windows.form sem o form seja a melhor solução, alias em alguns testes que tinha feito ele tinha um desempenho superior ao console!. vou editar minha resposta para tentar incluir o máximo de informação do primeiro método